# xfdesktop error after inactivity "None of the screen lock tools ran successfully, the screen will not be locked"

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, lock-screen, xfce4

I user lightdm and xfce on my laptop. It's a new installation. Every time the screen turns off from inactivity (or close the lid), I would see the lightdm login screen. However, after I log in, and after a few seconds, a window simply titled "Error" would pop up.

I would see the error too if I close the lid, unlock, then close the lid again in a few seconds. I don't even know where the error came from.

[image: The error message "None of the screen lock tools ran successfully, the screen will not be locked"]

Comment: I'm getting the same error message, also using arch linux and xfce. It's been happening the past two weeks or so. I wonder if it's a recently introduced package bug.

Comment: `ls -ltr /var/log/` should list some useful logs to paste the `tail` from.

Answer (score 5):

I don't use ArchLinux specifically but the problem keeps on appearing on different distros running XFCE DE due to possibly different reasons (not clearly known to me at the moment). Recently it appeared in Ubuntu when I installed [Clight](https://github.com/FedeDP/Clight). With Clight disabled, locking works fine.

By default `xfce4-power-manager` does not log any helpful output to `syslog` or `.xsession-errors`. In order to troubleshoot the problem, kill the auto-started daemon and start in foreground in debugging mode:

```
~$ xfce4-power-manager --quit
~$ xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon --debug
```

The following message appears when [`xfce_screensaver_lock`](https://github.com/xfce-mirror/xfce4-power-manager/blob/xfce4-power-manager-1.7.0/src/xfce-screensaver.c#L499) is called from [`xfpm_power_sleep`](https://github.com/xfce-mirror/xfce4-power-manager/blob/xfce4-power-manager-1.7.0/src/xfpm-power.c#L434) or [`xfpm_manager_lid_changed_cb`](https://github.com/xfce-mirror/xfce4-power-manager/blob/xfce4-power-manager-1.7.0/src/xfpm-manager.c#L456) and returns failure:

> None of the screen lock tools ran successfully, the screen will not be locked. Do you still want to continue to suspend the system?

So look into your screensaver, `xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /general/LockCommand` setting, and commands: `xflock4`, `xdg-screensaver`, `xscreensaver-command` etc.

However a simple solution is to not use XFCE Power Manager's `Lock screen when system is going to sleep` setting at all. Define a `systemd` service to run lock command before going to sleep and/or hibernate. An additional benefit is that this would lock the screen even if you suspend the system from commandline.

```
# /etc/systemd/system/screen_lock@.service

[Unit]
Description=Autolock screen before sleep, hibernate and hybrid-sleep
Before=sleep.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target

[Service]
User=%i                       # may also hardcode username here
Type=forking
Environment=DISPLAY=:0        # replace this with your $DISPLAY value
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xtrlock    # use whatever lock command
ExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 1

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

Enable the service:

```
~$ sudo systemctl enable screen_lock@<username>.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Got hit by this as well on *some but not all* of my Debian Buster installations (xfce4-power-manager v1.6.1-1). Did not dig deeper, but 'fixed' it by changing the source-code to **always call xflock4**:
In `xfce-screensaver.c` modify function `xfce_screensaver_lock` so it looks like:

```
gboolean
xfce_screensaver_lock (XfceScreenSaver *saver)
{
  /* maybe better use whole code of SCREENSAVER_TYPE_OTHER... */
  g_spawn_command_line_async ("xflock4", NULL);
  return TRUE;
}
```

I'm using mate-screensaver (yep, **in xfce**) and suspect that for some reason the `g_dbus_proxy_call_sync` in `case SCREENSAVER_TYPE_MATE` fails...

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was the **presence** of the **cinnamon-screensaver** DBus service files, even though it wasn't running. I found that out by running `dbus-monitor --session | grep -v '^ '` to see messages on DBus when I tried to suspend, and saw `Lock` commands being sent to `org.cinnamon.ScreenSaver` even though I don't use cinnamon-screensaver -- that seemed suspicious. I also saw an error message like `Type of message, "(yb)", does not match expected type "(b)"` when using another suspend path (through keyboard shortcut / xfce4-session).

Since I'm not using Cinnamon, my workaround was just to **uninstall cinnamon-screensaver** to remove the DBus configuration files that confused XFCE:

```
$ sudo apt purge cinnamon-screensaver
$ grep -r org.cinnamon.ScreenSaver /usr/share/dbus-1/
  # should not find any matches
# now re-login to make sure the session-wide DBus picks up the change
```

Answer (score 0):

The issues is also addressed here:
https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/-/issues/142

According to the referenced issue the problem might be caused due to the D-Bus interface `org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver` not having a method called `Lock`.

Sebastian @giwiniswut summerizes the issue as follows:

> - If locking the screen via the D-Bus interface fails the    xfce4-power-manager doesn't try to fall back to the user-specified
>   command line. [...]
> - The xfce4-power-manager has support for a number of specific    screensaver D-Bus interfaces but prioritises
>   org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver over most of them. Screensavers which
>   provide this interface without exposing all of their methods there as
>   well won't work properly. This currently affects the Cinnamon and
>   GNOME screensavers but presumable the MATE screensaver as well. There
>   is currently no proposed patch that changes this behavior.

In my case this also affects `xscreensaver`.

I created an AUR package for Arch Linux which uses the patch suggested by @maratbn in the linked issue:

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xfce4-power-manager-git-xsccomp

This solves the problem for me.

The patch seems to be only a temporary solution. It makes xfce4-power-manager handle the `SCREENSAVER_TYPE_FREEDESKTOP` case the same as `SCREENSAVER_TYPE_OTHER` and thereby invoking the `xfconf` `LockCommand`

EDIT: Unfortunately this seems not to work reliably. On my system after the a resume from suspend. xfce4-power-manager spawns endless xflock4 processes.

EDIT2: For me it works fine when setting the `xfce4-session/general/LockCommand`  in `xfconf` to

```
xscreensaver-command -lock
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not post link only answers as the linked site might change, rendering your answer useless. Instead quote the most important parts from the linked sites and provide the links for reference only.

Comment: @DarkDiamond Thanks for the hint. I added some more detailed information.